# a ListView with the items side by side

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm trying to make a custom photo gallery for my app. In essence, I'd like it to look like this.

[image: desired effect]

I'm not sure as to how I can use a ListView to accomplish this.

Help is appreciated.

Comment: look into either a GridView or RecyclerView's GridLayoutManager

Answer (score 0):

I encourage you to use RecyclerView, it's better than in performance.

after using RecyclerView, use GridLayoutManager with recyclerView, so you can split the items horizontally or vertically.

see this example.
https://www.journaldev.com/13792/android-gridlayoutmanager-example

Happy coding!